How can i reset each page when navigating in a single window in WPF?
I have this app in C# using WPF to manage users in active directory. To manage useres i have 3 pages, one for listing all of the users in the OU where the user has to select one user to view their data, anothere one to view the data form one of the users where the user can see their data or edit the data of the user and the last one is for editing the user. The problem is that when i write anything on the edit page, it stays there written even if i go back to the user page or the userslist page, the same happens in any textbox that i write, it stays there, only resets when i close the app but i want it to be able to write something, exit the page and that the changes that i made dont save, is there something i can do, any help would be useful, thanks. Here is the code for each one of them
List of users:
<ui:UiPage
    x:Class="Sysadmin.Views.Pages.UsersPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sysadmin.Views.Pages"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Sysadmin.Models"
    xmlns:ui="http://schemas.lepo.co/wpfui/2022/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Sysadmin.Converters" 
    xmlns:Interactivity="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
    Title="Users"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:UsersPage,
                                     IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    d:Background="{DynamicResource ApplicationBackgroundBrush}"
    Foreground="{DynamicResource TextFillColorPrimaryBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>

        <converters:EmptyToCollapsedConverter x:Key="EmptyToCollapsedConverter"/>
        <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <converters:BoolToColorConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter"/>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ui:SymbolIcon 
            Margin="4"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Symbol="Person24"/>
                <TextBlock 
    Grid.Column="1"
    
    Style="{StaticResource ListNameStyle}">
<Run Text="{Binding CN}" />
                    <Run Text="(" />
    <Run Text="{Binding SamAccountName}" />
                     <Run Text=")" />
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock  
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Visibility="{Binding Description, Converter={StaticResource EmptyToCollapsedConverter}}"
            Text="{Binding Description}"
            Style="{StaticResource ListDescriptionStyle}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>


    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="16,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock 
                Margin="24"
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Text="Usuaris"
                Style="{StaticResource TitleDetailPageStyle}"/>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <ui:AutoSuggestBox MinWidth="200" Icon="Search12" PlaceholderText="Busca..." TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"/>
                <Menu VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                    <ui:MenuItem Command="{Binding ViewModel.AddCommand}" x:Name="mnuAdd">
                        <ui:MenuItem.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ui:SymbolIcon Symbol="Add12" Margin="0,0,8,0" />
                                <TextBlock>Afegeix</TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ui:MenuItem.Header>
                    </ui:MenuItem>
                    <ui:MenuItem x:Name="mnuSort">
                        <ui:MenuItem.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock>Ordena</TextBlock>
                                <ui:SymbolIcon Symbol="ChevronDown20" Margin="4,0,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ui:MenuItem.Header>
                        <ui:MenuItem Tag="asc" Header="Per nom (A-Z)" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Command="{Binding ViewModel.SortCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Click="MenuSort_Click"/>
                        <ui:MenuItem Tag="desc" Header="Per nom (Z-A)" IsCheckable="True" Command="{Binding ViewModel.SortCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Click="MenuSort_Click"/>
                    </ui:MenuItem>
                    <ui:MenuItem x:Name="mnuFilter">
                        <ui:MenuItem.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock>Filtres</TextBlock>
                                <ui:SymbolIcon Symbol="ChevronDown20" Margin="4,0,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ui:MenuItem.Header>
                        <ui:MenuItem Tag="all" Header="Tots" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Click="MenuFilter_Click" Command="{Binding ViewModel.FilterCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                        <ui:MenuItem Tag="enabled" Header="Activats" IsCheckable="True" Click="MenuFilter_Click" Command="{Binding ViewModel.FilterCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                        <ui:MenuItem Tag="disabled" Header="Desactivats" IsCheckable="True" Click="MenuFilter_Click" Command="{Binding ViewModel.FilterCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                        <ui:MenuItem Tag="locked" Header="Tancats" IsCheckable="True" Click="MenuFilter_Click" Command="{Binding ViewModel.FilterCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                        <ui:MenuItem Tag="expired" Header="Expirats" IsCheckable="True" Click="MenuFilter_Click" Command="{Binding ViewModel.FilterCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                        <ui:MenuItem Tag="never_expires" Header="Mai expiren" IsCheckable="True" Click="MenuFilter_Click" Command="{Binding ViewModel.FilterCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                    </ui:MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <ListView Grid.Row="1"
          x:Name="users"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Users, Mode=OneWay}" >
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding IsRed, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsRed}" Value="True" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#a37070" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Interactivity:EventTrigger  EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <Interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedItemsChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=users}" />
                </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListView>






        <ui:ProgressRing IsIndeterminate="True" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding ViewModel.IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />

    </Grid>
</ui:UiPage>


the xaml.cs
namespace Sysadmin.Views.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for DataView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UsersPage : INavigableView<ViewModels.UsersViewModel>
    {
        private IStateService stateService;
        public ViewModels.UsersViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get;
        }

        public UsersPage(ViewModels.UsersViewModel viewModel, IStateService stateService)
        {
            this.stateService = stateService;
            ViewModel = viewModel;

            InitializeComponent();

            if ((stateService.IsLoggedIn == true && stateService.IsAdmin == false))
            {
                mnuAdd.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        public UsersPage()
        {
        }

        private void MenuSort_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem menu = (MenuItem)sender;
            foreach (MenuItem item in mnuSort.Items)
            {
                if (item != menu)
                    item.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }

        private void MenuFilter_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem menu = (MenuItem)sender;
            foreach (MenuItem item in mnuFilter.Items)
            {
                if (item != menu)
                    item.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }

        private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is AutoSuggestBox)
                ViewModel.SearchCommand.Execute(((AutoSuggestBox)sender).Text);
        }
    }
}
 private void MemberOfControl_Error(string ErrorMessage)
        {
            snackbar.Message = ErrorMessage;
            snackbar.Show();
        }


    }
}

I cant show the code of Editusers and userpage because stackoverflow marks it as spam and because of word limitations but if anyone wants to help i can post it in a reply. Thanks in advance.


You have not shown how you navigate and edit objects. You don't have to post your real code. Just create a new WPF project to create a minimal example that reproduces your scenario. We can only help if we have something to review. Right now, you only show a single Page with a lot of noise. Totally useless in order to help you - I'm sorry to say that.

In general, you have to create new instances of whatever you use as navigation destination.
